# differences between Realtime Database data types

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am thinking about what actual format store in database?

like is there any diiferences between `ref('data/timestamp').set(ServerValue.timestamp)` and `ref('data').set({timestamp:ServerValue.timestamp})`?

So does array and list are they exists for simplify client side code? or it's actually matter on database side? I am looking for the basic types that acatual store in database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference in the value of the `timestamp` node that both fragments store in the database. In both cases that value will be a long numeric value, indicating the number of milliseconds since the epoch.

The difference is in what happens to any existing **other** nodes you may have under `data` already. Say that you start with:

```
data: {
  name: "flutroid",
  timestamp: 0
}
```

Then running `ref('data/timestamp').set(ServerValue.timestamp)` will lead to:

```
data: {
  name: "flutroid",
  timestamp: 1664028303669
}
```

While running `ref('data').set({timestamp:ServerValue.timestamp})` leads to:

```
data: {
  timestamp: 1664028303669
}
```

So in this last example the `name` node (and any other nodes under `data`) were deleted and only `timestamp` remains.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Now I understand that if I writed map to database it just became part of path. But Is there any diifferent to list and array types? I think these two types just create key automatically for me, Am I right?

Comment: JavaScript/JSON doesn't have a list type, so it's hard to say what the difference is between that and an array without seeing what you mean exactly. If this is an important question, I recommend starting a new post with a [minimal repro](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).